# Is is poor practice to place a significant number of functions inside of your AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to combine several small, similar, web apps into a single web app with multiple views. The problem I was facing is correctly scoping my objects and functions to the appropriate view. This is where Angular came in.

I can scope my functions and objects to a specific module. Specifically functions such as data validation (For a form of sorts) can go inside of a specific controller instead of being global functions.

Functions that would manipulate the DOM are being put inside of directives, and reusable code is being put into services. But i have a lot of one off functions that need to be scoped to a specific view that will sit inside a single controller.

Is this considered a bad practice? If so, what is the appropriate way to go about this?

Comment: You can define controller for a directive, think of it as small app with template, link function and controller.  Also use routing in your single page app and load corresponding controller when you accessing particular route in your app, all code that is shared among several controllers (normal controller or directive controller doesnt matter) should go to factory/service.

Comment: Also switch to ControllerAs syntax for routes and directive, this way you can use inheritance for controllers.

Comment: could you provide some specific examples of what you consider a bad practice

Comment: Shouldn't really matter where you put one off functions. General consensus is keep controllers as thin as possible though